# Can I unit test an inner function in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, doctest

Is there any way to write `unittests` or `doctests` for `innerfunc`?

```
def outerfunc():
    def innerfunc():
        do_something()
    return innerfunc()
```

Comment: You normally don't do this: the API is the enclosing function, and inner functions are analogous to named blocks of code in the function.  You don't test them directly, just as you don't test a single loop inside a function directly; you test the inputs to the function that exercise the code block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only if you provide a way to extract the inner function object itself, e.g.

```
def outerfunc(calltheinner=True):
    def innerfunc():
        do_something()
    if calltheinner:
        return innerfunc()
    else:
        return innerfunc
```

If your outer function insists on hiding the inner one entirely inside itself (never letting it percolate outside when properly cajoled to do so), your unit-tests are powerless to defeat this strong bid for extreme and total privacy;-).

Answer (score 4):

This is actually an old open Python issue:

- [Issue 1650090: doctest doesn't find nested functions](http://bugs.python.org/issue1650090)

There's a candidate patch (from 2007) that makes doctest find nested functions, but someone probably needs to push this.